# How do I configure the hostname for the GitLab NixOS service?

Tags: configuration, ruby-on-rails, gitlab, nixos

I am trying to deploy a new GitLab instance on NixOS 20.09.1632.a6a3a368dda (Nightingale).

I have this rather minimal configuration.nix:

```
{ modulesPath, ... }:
let
  host = "example.org";
  adminEmail = "admin@example.org";
in
{
  imports = [ "${modulesPath}/virtualisation/amazon-image.nix" ];
  ec2.hvm = true;

  services.gitlab = rec {
    enable = true;

    inherit host;
    port = 80;

    # You, dear sysadmin, have to make these files exist.
    initialRootPasswordFile = "/tmp/gitlab-secrets/initial-password";

    secrets = rec {
      # A file containing 30 "0" characters.
      secretFile = "/tmp/gitlab-secrets/zeros";
      dbFile = secretFile;
      otpFile = secretFile;
      # openssl genrsa 2048 > jws.rsa
      jwsFile = "/tmp/gitlab-secrets/jws.rsa";
    };
  };

  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    user = "gitlab";
    virtualHosts = {
      "${host}" = {
        locations."/" = {
          # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
          proxyPass = "http://unix:/var/gitlab/state/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket";
        };
      };
    };
  };

  networking.firewall = {
    enable = true;
    allowPing = false;
    allowedTCPPorts = [
      22
      80
    ];
  };
}
```

When activating this configuration, many processes are started (redis, postgresql, sidekiq, etc).  However, nginx (thanks to, I assume, GitLab's Rails HTTP server) responds to requests for `/` with this:

```
* Connected to example.org (X.X.X.X) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.72.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 19:38:40 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
< Location: http://localhost/users/sign_in
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: experimentation_subject_id=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IklqZGhabU0zWXpVNExUSmxNR1F0TkdZMlpTMWlZVEkwTFdKak1EVTFaREZoTURJd1ppST0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImNvb2tpZS5leHBlcmltZW50YXRpb25fc3ViamVjdF9pZCJ9fQ%3D%3D--cbf53392028ed41f7c582a64e643476a5c2aab6b; path=/; expires=Mon, 11 Feb 2041 19:38:40 -0000; HttpOnly
< X-Request-Id: 545cc04e-1689-4351-b5a9-ca171f1a85d4
< X-Runtime: 0.060596
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.org left intact
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Since `localhost` is not `example.org`, this fails.

How do I configure GitLab to know its own hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired behavior can achieved with the `proxy_set_header` [NGINX directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header):

```
proxy_set_header Host       $host;
```

If you include this line in the reverse proxy configuration, NGINX will rewrite the host header (i.e. `localhost`) sent back from the upstream server (i.e. GitLab) with the hostname from the original request (i.e. `example.org`). Enabling the `services.nginx.recommendedProxySettings` option in NixOS will generate NGINX configuration with the [directive included](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/09f59df5d3c34df1dcbb1610e4c196ba877f4b35/nixos/modules/services/web-servers/nginx/default.nix#L60).